# Unable to connect to domain controller from laptop

Tags: domain-controller, laptop, networking

i have a windows 2003 domain controller and am unable to get one of my laptops to join to it.

When i try to change from workgroup to domain it connects, asks for for a username and password and after i put them in and press enter it says that the network location could not be reached..

Can anyone help?

Laptop is Win7 x64. Connectioned with LAN.

Answer (score 4):

Is the laptop configured to use the proper DNS server? This would be the DNS server that is holding your AD DNS domain name space, which is presumably your DC. If not, then configure it to use that DNS server.

Comment: +1 99.9% of AD connection problems are basic IP configuration (IP, subnet, gateway, DNS)

Comment: Hi all, my DNS server is the same as the DC. both the DNS and GATEWAY are pointing to the ip address of the DC. assigned by DHCP the subnet is the same...

Answer (score 1):

In lieu of DNS being a problem, try blowing away the PC's computer account and recreating it.  This has solved many stupid AD problems for me.